# How do I make sure a certain "finalization" section is the last one executed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, finalization

I have many units with "finalization" sections in my Delphi 7 projects.

How do I make sure to execute some code last?

I tried to write a "finalization" section in the .dpr file but it does not compile.

Comment: Initialization & Finalization come from ancient Pascal. Usually they are used to do global things, like class un/registration etc... But this is not so OOP style. Try to avoid them, a better approach is to  use Object/Class methods to initialize/deinitialize things.

Comment: FWIW, the newest Delphi has class constructors and destructors which are guaranteed to run before the first access to the class and after the last access to the class respectively. They can often replace the initialization and finalization sections completely. But I don't think the order in which they are called is defined.

Answer (score 5):

There's a good explanation on the finalization ordering for code in [Unit finalization order for application compiled with run-time packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628859/unit-finalization-order-for-application-compiled-with-run-time-packages) - the questioner came up with a reasonable way to ensure that his ordering worked - add the module **at the start** of the uses clause of the project, and ensure that the module in question **does not use any other units**.

**Edit**: Took David Heffernan's addendum on-board.

Comment: Add the module at the start of the uses clause, and ensure that it uses **no** other units.

Comment: Still if you can fix your dependencies and orders without relying on this, your code will be more reusable and safer.